# IIS7 & WIndows Authentication - authenticating to the wrong domain

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-authentication

I have an IIS 7 web app that is using Windows authentication. Currently, everything is set up correctly based on all that I've been able to find on the web.

What's happening is when a user tries to get to that domain, they see the authentication popup, but they are being requested to authenticate to "servername.domain" instead of just the domain .... How do I get IIS 7 (or the browser for that matter) to realize that windows authentication should be to the domain, not to the machine hosting the IIS 7 instance??

Thanks,

Steve G.

Answer (score 0):

What prompts in IE is out of IIS's control. It is not IIS that asks you to authenticate to "servername.domain".